# Python: for multiple properties use one getter and setter method

Tags: python-3.x, oop, getter-setter, python-class

I have created a class that has multiple properties. I want to use one function for the getter method and the second one for the setter method.

```
class person:

    def __init__(self, fname, lname, city, state):
        # make all attributes as private
        self._fname = fname
        self._lname = lname
        self._city = city
        self._state = state

    @property  # get method
    def fname(self):
        return self._fname

    @fname.setter  # set method
    def fname(self,fname):
        self._fname = fname

    @property
    def lname(self):
        return self._lname

    @lname.setter
    def lname(self,lname):
        self._lname = lname

    @property
    def city(self):
        return self._city

    @city.setter
    def city(self, city):
        self._city = city

    @property
    def state(self):
        return self._state

    @state.setter
    def state(self, state):
        self._state = state
```

How to use all properties for one get methods and one set method?

e.g.:

```
def get(self):
    return self._attr

def set(self,value):
    self._attr = value
```

Comment: You could write a custom [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), then do e.g. `city = my_descriptor('_city')`. Here's one I had reviewed earlier: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/98892/32391. But in this example there's no point to any of those things being properties, as the getters and setters don't *do* anything.

Comment: The point of having computed attributes is to NOT have to write getters/setters when you don't need them - and they are definitly not needed in your example. So just remove all those properties, use plain public attributes instead (this will be 100% functionally equivalent, without the overhead of the descriptor and method invocations), and if/when you find out you need to add some effective getter/setter for one given attribute, turn it (and it alone) into a property (or whatever custom descriptor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class person:
    def __set_name__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None) -> object:
        return obj.__dict__.get(self.name)

    def __set__(self, obj, value) -> None:
        obj.__dict__[self.name] = value

my_value = person
my_values.fname = 'Shivam'
my_values.lname = 'Gupta'

print(my_values.fname)  #--> Shivam
print(my_values.lname)  #--> Gupta
```